# What is the key of Required SSL while creating Glue Connection (MONGODB connection type) in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-connection

i am trying to create a Glue connection using cloud formation. The connection type is MONGODB. I am not able to set the ssl details here. Tried MONGODB_ENFORCE_SSL but it's not working even though build not failed.

```
Some-Name:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Connection
    Properties:
      CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
      ConnectionInput:
        Name: connection
        Description: "Connection to DB"
        ConnectionType: "MONGODB"
        ConnectionProperties:
          CONNECTION_URL: !Ref ConnectionUri
          USERNAME: !Ref User
          PASSWORD: !Ref Password
          MONGODB_ENFORCE_SSL: "false"
        PhysicalConnectionRequirements:
          SecurityGroupIdList:
            - "sg-something"
          SubnetId: "subnet-something"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JDBC_ENFORCE_SSL` seems to be the default for JDBC connections and even Network connections